# unique solution for a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $l,f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions of class $C^1$

prove that the system
\begin{array}
\\
x' &=l(x), \quad x(t_0)=x_0 \\
y'&= f(x)y, \quad  y(t_0)=y_0  
\end{array}

has unique solution.

I know that to verify the uniqueness of the solution I must see that the partial derivative is continuous, but for this "general" case, I don't understand how to do it. Also, is it so important that $l,f$ they are class $C^1$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Picard-Lindelof theorem?

Comment: yes i know the  theorem, how should i use it?

Comment: Well, if $F(x,y)=l(x)$, what's $\partial F/\partial x$ and $\partial F/\partial y$? And are they continuous? Similarly for $G(x,y) = f(x) y$.